# R X-axis Date Labels using plot()

Tags: r, plot, label, axis

Using the `plot()` function in R, I'm trying to produce a scatterplot of points of the form `(SaleDate,SalePrice) = (saldt,sapPr)` from a time-series, cross-section real estate sales dataset in dataframe format. My problem concerns labels for the X-axis.  Just about any series of annual labels would be adequate, e.g. 1999,2000,...,2013 or 1999-01-01,...,2013-01-01. What I'm getting now, a single label, 2000, at what appears to be the proper location won't work.

The following is my call to `plot()`:

```
plot(r12rgr0$saldt, r12rgr0$salpr/1000, type="p", pch=20, col="blue", cex.axis=.75, 
     xlim=c(as.Date("1999-01-01"),as.Date("2014-01-01")),
     ylim=c(100,650), 
     main="Heritage Square Sales Prices $000s 1990-2014",xlab="Sale Date",ylab="$000s")
```

The `xlim` and `ylim` are called out to bound the date and price ranges of the data to be plotted; note prices are plotted as $000s. `r12rgr0$saldt` really *is* a date; `str(r12rgr0$saldt)` returns:

```
Date[1:4190], format: "1999-10-26" "2013-07-06" "2003-08-25" NA NA "2000-05-24"  xx
```

I have reviewed several threads here concerning similar questions, and see that the solution probably lies with turning off the default X-axis behavior and using axis.date, but i) At my current level of R skill, I'm not sure I'd be able to solve the problem, and ii) I wonder why the plotting defaults are producing these rather puzzling (to me, at least) results?

Addl Observations: The Y-axis labels are just fine 100, 200,..., 600.  The general appearance of the scatterplot indicates the called-for date ranges are being observed and the relative positions of the plotted points are correct. Replacing `xlim=`... as above with `xlim=c("1999-01-01","2014-01-01")`

or

```
xlim=c(as.numeric(as.character("1999-01-01")),as.numeric(as.character("2014-01-01")))
```

or

```
xlim=c(as.POSIXct("1999-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d"),as.POSIXct("2014-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d"))
```

all result in error messages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With plots it's very hard to reproduce results with out sample data. Here's a sample I'll use

```
dd<-data.frame(
  saldt=seq(as.Date("1999-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-10"), by="6 mon"),
  salpr = cumsum(rnorm(31))
)
```

A simple plot with

```
with(dd, plot(saldt, salpr))
```

produces a few year marks

[image]

If i wanted more control, I could use `axis.Date` as you alluded to

```
with(dd, plot(saldt, salpr, xaxt="n"))
axis.Date(1, at=seq(min(dd$saldt), max(dd$saldt), by="30 mon"), format="%m-%Y")
```

which gives

[image]

note that `xlim` will only zoom in parts of the plot. It is not directly connected to the axis labels but the axis labels will adjust to provide a "pretty" range to cover the data that is plotted. Doing just

```
xlim=c(as.Date("1999-01-01"),as.Date("2014-01-01"))
```

is the correct way to zoom the plot. No need for conversion to numeric or POSIXct.

Comment: I think maybe plot() draws a chart, including the pretty axes labels, before it zooms the view a la xlim or ylim.  I have a couple sales date outliers in my dataframe, including an obs in 1909.  When I plot() without using xlim, that is including the outlier, I get a nice set of X-axis labels at 20 yr intervals starting at 1920; all but one of the graphed points are squeeaed way over on the rhs of the chart. And the only label under the big concentration of points is 2000 -- right in the same relative position in which it appears in the zoomed version using xlim. Can't be a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a plot in real time and don't mind some warnings, you can just pass, e.g., `format = "%Y-%m-%d"` in the plot function.  For instance:

```
plot(seq((Sys.Date()-9),Sys.Date(), 1), runif(10), xlab = "Date", ylab = "Random")
```

yields:
[image]
while:

```
plot(seq((Sys.Date()-9), Sys.Date(), 1), runif(10), format = "%Y-%m-%d", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Random")
```

yields:
[image]
with lots of warnings about `format` not being a graphical parameter.