# How to obtain an ordered object for a date variable that has been formatted?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to format my date variable to `%d %b %Y` (e.g. 05 May 2020). However, once it has been formatted, it becomes a character variable and sorting the variable from the earliest date to the latest date would not be possible (e.g. 05 May 2020 is sorted before 26 Apr 2020).

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1588204800, 1587945600, 1588464000, 1588032000,  
                                        1588291200, 1588377600, 1588118400), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                       "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
# > df
# Date
# 1 2020-04-30
# 2 2020-04-27
# 3 2020-05-03
# 4 2020-04-28
# 5 2020-05-01
# 6 2020-05-02
# 7 2020-04-29
```

Here is how it looks like sorting a formatted date variable:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = format(Date, "%d %b %Y")) %>% 
  arrange(Date)
#          Date
# 1 01 May 2020
# 2 02 May 2020
# 3 03 May 2020
# 4 27 Apr 2020
# 5 28 Apr 2020
# 6 29 Apr 2020
# 7 30 Apr 2020
```

So, this is what I have done, which works, but I would like to know if this is really correct or if there are alternatives to solve this.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = factor(Date, labels = format(sort(unique(Date)), "%d %b %Y"), ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(Date)
#          Date
# 1 27 Apr 2020
# 2 28 Apr 2020
# 3 29 Apr 2020
# 4 30 Apr 2020
# 5 01 May 2020
# 6 02 May 2020
# 7 03 May 2020
```

**Edit:**
Actually the reason behind wanting to format it and arranging it, is so that I can have direct access to more readable date formats when building my dashboard for my users.

When it comes to `ggplot()`, even after you do `arrange` and `mutate` with `format`, the facetted plots, will always give in sorted character order. Example below:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  mutate(n = 1:n(),
         Date = format(Date, "%d %b %Y")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = n)) +
  facet_wrap(~Date)
```

Comment: The correct way would be to keep them as Date variable only and not use `format` if you want to use them ahead in your analysis. Once you use `format` it becomes character and can't do much about it. Another option is to have two columns, one with `format` and another with date.

Comment: @RonakShah The reason why I format it as such is because I would like to use it directly in the tables and plots when building my dashboard. I couldnt find a way to see whether the levels and labels are correctly mapped in my question above.

Comment: Why not chose the second option then? Keep two columns one with date to do processing and another one with format.

Comment: As an aside, date axes in base R and the ggplot2 package allow you to specify the date formats during the plotting. E.g. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481176/r-x-axis-date-labels-using-plot and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748384/formatting-dates-on-x-axis-in-ggplot2

Comment: @HNSKD I have provided a simple solution below, if it answers your question please make sure to accept the answer, if not please clarify what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use dates in plots the main idea is to adjust the factor levels based on order in which you want to show data. `arrange` the dates first and attach factor levels based on occurrence of dates.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number(),
         Date = format(Date, "%d %b %Y"), 
         Date = factor(Date, levels = unique(Date))) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x = n)) + facet_wrap(~Date)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My original solution is below, but the better solution is so simple it hurts a little that I didn't spot it immediately - do your `arrange()` *before* your `mutate()` - at that point it is a date-type variable so will sort the way you want it to:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  mutate(Date = format(Date, "%d %b %Y"))
```

Giving:

```
         Date
1 27 Apr 2020
2 28 Apr 2020
3 29 Apr 2020
4 30 Apr 2020
5 01 May 2020
6 02 May 2020
7 03 May 2020
```

Alternatively, you could add an `as.Date(..., format = "%d %b %Y")` to your `arrange()`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = format(Date, "%d %b %Y")) %>%
  arrange(as.Date(Date, format = "%d %b %Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer the tidyverse solution for dates - lubridate. Here:

```
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>% 
  arrange(Date)
```

In short, you can parse your dates by combining `d` for day, `m` for month and `y` for year. You can add time, too. For example,

```
ymd_hms("20150102 12:23:01")
```

As the example shows we do not have to bother about the seperator. If you have access [this](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=lubridate&btnG=#d=gs_qabs&u=%23p%3DTOO1y756aYYJ) is a nice paper on that package. Otherwise, there are many tutorials out there on lubridate.