# How to simplify date in graph axis to month and year?

Tags: r, date

Apologies for a question on something which is probably very straightforward. I am very new to R.
I have a dataframe which contains dates in a year,month,day format e.g. "2020-05-28". I wanted to stratify the data at month level, so I used the "floor_date" function. However, now the dates read as "2020-05-01" etc. This is absolutely fine for the data set itself, but I am creating epidemiological curves and want to change the dates to "2020-05" etc. on the legend. Could anyone provide some guidance on how to do this? I can't simply replace the pattern "01" with a blank as I need to keep 01 on month level (January) visible.

Comment: You could improve your chances of finding help here by adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Adding a MRE and an example of the desired output (in code form, not tables and pictures) makes it much easier for others to find and test an answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you! P.S. Here is [a good overview on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481176/r-x-axis-date-labels-using-plot) and its answers give you what you need?